# figure.show() doesn't show

Tags: python, matplotlib

I maintain a fancy plotting package that implements the function `plot_foobar()`. It returns the figure with the plot so the user can do something with it, e.g., save it to a file (`savefig()`) or show it. Unfortunately, `show()` doesn't do anything.

MWE:

```py
def plot_foobar():
    # fancy plotting routing in a package
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot([1, 2], [3, 4])
    return fig


# the user invokes the plotting function and gets back the figure object
fig = plot_foobar()

# saving the file works
# fig.savefig("out.png")

# :(
fig.show()

# works, but is clumsy:
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# plt.show()
```

Is this intended?

If yes, I could of course ask the user the import matplotlib and call `plt.show()` herself -- that works. I would rather avoid exposing this information and the force the user to import something just for showing the figure. Is there some other object I could return on which `show()`, `savefig()` etc. works?

Comment: Pyplot is where the GUI that can show anything is started, so it is not possible to “show” unless you have the GUI started. Matplotlib realizes this is kind of dumb and is working on a bit of a re architecture of this, but it will take a while.

Comment: Thanks Jody for the reply. I didn't quite catch where the GUI is started. At `import matplotlib.pyplot`? And is there a bug report/issue that I can follow about the rewrite?

Comment: I think https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/18852

Comment: A more recent bug report: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/19956

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fundamental problem here is that the matplotlib "show loop" is a global object. There are some efforts to try and make `fig.show()` actually do something, but it's not around the corner. For now, one could return the global `plt` object

```py
def plot_foobar():
    # fancy plotting routing in a package
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot([1, 2], [3, 4])
    return plt
```

For the user, it's not any different from `fig` in that one can `plt.show()` or perform any other action on the current figure.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a decorator to the Figure instance to call the plt.show() inside it:

```
def show_figure(f):
    '''
    Decorator to change fig.show() behavior.
    '''
    def wrapper():
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        f()  # call the original fig.show(), remove this line if there is no need to run fig.show()
        plt.show()

    return wrapper

def plot_foobar():
    # fancy plotting routing in a package
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot([1, 2], [3, 4])

    fig.show = show_figure(fig.show)  # assign a decorator

    return fig

# the user invokes the plotting function and gets back the figure object
fig = plot_foobar()
fig.show()
```